# Best way to manage filters in a collection

Tags: symfony, collections, api-platform.com

I have three collections operations on one ApiResource that have differents `normalization_context` and `filters`.

- `/equipments` Retrieve all equipments (filtered on the current user)
- `/equipments/A` Retrieve all equipments matching rules A
- `/equipments/B` Retrieve all equipments matching rules B

Some filters are set on nested properties (ids of related entities). I want to give the API consumer the values it can use for certains filters. Let say I have a company filter shared by all endpoints.

- For `/equipments` the allowed values are 1,2,3
- For `/equipments/A` the allowed values are 4,5,6
- For `/equipments/B` the allowed values are 1,3,5

The solution I see is to add `.../filters` endpoint for each operations that will return filters with allowed values.

```
GET /equipments/filters

[
    {
        'name': 'company',
        'type': integer,
        'choices': [
            'Company 1': 1,
            'Company 2': 2,
            'Company 3': 3,
        ]
    },
    {
        'name': 'operator',
        'type': autocomplete,
        'url': /equipments/filters/operator?q={q}
    }
]
```

**Bonus question**: If this is a good solution, where and how can I add theses operations in the JSON-LD/Hydra documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

Most API documentation formats including Swagger and JSON-LD (supported by API Platform) allows to specify valid value for filters without requiring to do something custom.

With Swagger, you can use `enum` property of the `parameter` object to defined valid values: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/enums/

```
paths:
  /equipments/B:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: company
          description: A company filter
          type: integer
          enum: [1, 3, 5]
```

If you prefer using Hydra, you can use templated links to achieve what you want:

```
{
  "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/context.jsonld",
  "@type": "IriTemplate",
  "template": "/equipments/B{?company}",
  "mappings": [
    {
      "@type": "IriTemplateMapping",
      "variable": "company",
      "property": "http://example.com/myCompanyType"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you need to return values either dynamically by adding an endpoint returning applicable values, or directly in the vocabulary in the vocabulary if the list is static (e.g. http://schema.org/ActionStatusType).

To add such informations to API Platform, you need to decorate the builtin services generating the documentation. Example for Swagger: https://github.com/api-platform/docs/blob/master/core/swagger.md#override-swagger-documentation

Comment: I've read about Templated Links in the Hydra specification. But I don't see where to add the endpoint for applicable values.

Comment: You can just put its IRI in the `property` value.

Comment: So it can be different for each `/equipements` endpoint, seems good.

Not really optimal from a network performance perspective though. In order to display a list with filters you will have to make an additionnal request for each filters.

Comment: you may include several collections in the same JSON-LD document. The format is very flexible

Comment: Don't know I could do that ! I'm still a beginner in REST API :) Thanks for your help

Comment: Hum I don't find the right syntax for this. Do I include collection directly in the property (https://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld/#embedding) ?